# Unable to open multiple jquery dialogs when iterating through instance variable in rails 3

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

please help with the following:(using rails 3 and jquery)
In my view i have:

```
<% @project.each do |pro| %>
  <a href="#", id="opendialog"><%= pro.name %></a>
  <div id="dialog">
     <%= pro.description %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

In my application.js file i have:

```
$(function() {
    $( '#dialog' ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 600,
        modal: true
    });
    $('#opendialog').click(function(){
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
    return false;
    });
});
```

The code executes fine for the first record found, where i am able to click on the link and the dialog box opens, however for the second and successive records returned, it does not display the dialog box. Is it possible to write the href as a link_to helper(tried with no luck).

Thanks in advance, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating multiple `<div>`s with the same ID, which is a violation of the HTML spec since IDs must be unique.

Try changing it to a class instead:

```
<% @project.each do |pro| %>
  <a href="#", class="opendialog"><%= pro.name %></a>
  <div class="dialog">
     <%= pro.description %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

and

```
$(function() {
    $('.dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 600,
        modal: true
    });
    $('.opendialog').click(function(){
        $('.dialog').dialog('open');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks andrew, can't believe i did'nt see that. Time to take a break

Comment: It works fine except that each time i click the link it opens all the dialog boxes one after another. how can i solve this. thank for the help again.

Comment: Ah, change `$('.dialog').dialog('open');` to `$(this).dialog('open');`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not using the same ID twice. If you opened the dialog for the first time, when you close it make sure you destroy it completely so it doesn't remain hidden in DOM.

`.dialog( "destroy" )`